# Soundcloud custom player HTML generation/ stacking order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, soundcloud

I am no javascript whiz, not a programmer at all.

I want to change the stacking order of elements that make up the Soundcloud custom player in the HTML. I know that these can be positioned using CSS, but my preference for what I am doing would be to reorder the divs that the player generates, so that I can use default document flow to efficiently layout my player.

The divs come out in this order - not sure how this is generated from the soundcloud link, but I would like to figure this out:

```
  <div class="sc-player">
      <ol class="sc-artwork-list">
      </ol>
      <div class="sc-info"></div>
      <div class="sc-controls"></div>
      <ol class="sc-trackslist"></ol>
      <div class="sc-scrubber">
        <div class="sc-volume-slider"></div>
        <div class="sc-time-span">
          <div class="sc-waveform-container"></div>
          <div class="sc-buffer"></div>
          <div class="sc-played"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-time-indicators"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Does the Soundcloud custom player generate the HTML divs from the javascript? Where is this in the javascript file, so I can hack it, or perhaps taret this with a function on my HTML page to change the order?

Or is the HTML somehow downloaded from Soundcloud when the embedded track is (and therefore editing the HTML stacking order is no possible?) I couldn't see where this mights happen in the javascript.

Slightly wierd question but I'm trying to learn better how this plugin works, thank you. I won't paste the javascript here, but the files are located here https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the source here: https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/blob/master/js/sc-player.js

Search for “Generate custom skinnable HTML/CSS” – this is where HTML is being generated, you could modify it, if you like.

Comment: Thank you so much - so great to get a prompt and some encouragement from someone who knows what they are doing! I have solved the problem, I had noticed that bit of code, but was confused by change in syntax for appending the div.sc-scrubber, which then appears after the list. I commented out .append('<div class="sc-scrubber"></div>') and added $scrubber = $('<div class="sc-scrubber"></div>').appendTo($player),
above $list = $('<ol class="sc-trackslist"></ol>').appendTo($player); DONE! Thanks again.